# Simple Javascript removing class

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to remove a class on mouseenter with Javascript. Can people explain whats causing it not to work? I am new to JS. The function works with an Alert so i know the function is working so it must be the remove class line thats causing the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="left-filter">
         <div class="left">
           <h1 class="heading1">hi</h1>
           <a href="" class="landing-btn">Shop</a>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var left = document.querySelector('.left');
    var container = document.querySelector('container');
    left.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    container.classList.remove('.left-filter');
    })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `container.classList.remove('left-filter');`

Comment: Still is not removing!

Comment: Sorry my mistake it is It is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`container.classList.remove('.left-filter');` should be `container.classList.remove('left-filter');`

you only mention the name of the class in `remove` to remove the class. Not with `.`

Moreover `document.querySelector('container');` should be `document.querySelector('.container');`

On a side note. If there are more than one elements with class `.container`, `document.querySelector('.container')` will only select the first one.

If you want to attach events to all of those elements, you'll have to use `document.querySelectorAll('.container')` , this will give you the node list and you'll have to loop through this list to attach events to all of the nodes

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but this is still not working.

Comment: Apologies, it is!

Comment: @Blue Glad to know that :) . Consider accepting the answer if it resolved your issue

Comment: Did it there! Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Your selector for `container` is wrong. You are missing a `.` before the selector:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
                                        ^
                                        |
                                        ---- This dot was missing
```

The dot indicates that you are selecting a element by the class.
Without it, javascript was searching for a element named `container`.

Also the line that removes the class is wrong, the `.` is not needed here:

```
container.classList.remove('left-filter');
```